# How to convert a cURL command to a graphQL REST datasource command in JS

Tags: javascript, rest, curl, graphql, apollo

I have the following cURL command which works fine, but I can't figure out how to get it working with a [GraphQL RESTdatasource](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/data-sources/#rest-data-source) due to the options it uses. I've censored some info so this command won't work, but the structure is the same as the one that does.

```
curl -k -u app-user:app-password https://splunk.com:8000/servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export?output_mode=json -d search=" search source="dev-app" | head 4"
```

I used an online converter to get the following NodeJs code, which also works.

```
var request = require('request');

var dataString = 'search= search source=dev-app | head 4';

var options = {
    url: 'https://splunk.com:8000/servicesNS/admin/search/search/jobs/export?output_mode=json',
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataString,
    auth: {
        'user': 'app-user',
        'pass': 'app-password'
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

I was unable to get this working with the RESTdatasource's `this.get()` function. At least one of the problems I noticed was that it's converting the `options.auth` object to `[object Object]`, but I think there are more issues.

Can anyone help me convert that to a `this.get()` call? Here is an example of a sample project using it: https://github.com/benawad/apollo-datasource-rest-example/blob/master/RandomUserDataSource.ts